# iPod dock with amplified line out and charging?

Tags: audio, ipod, charging, lightning

I have an Aux connector in my car that I'm plugging my iPod into via the headphone outputs. It's almost OK, but the sound quality isn't what it could be - the levels are too low, and cranking up the volume in the car exposes some low-level noise. There's also something not quite right about it that I can't put my finger on.

There are tons of adapters that plug into the docking port and expose a line out connection, which should be better than the headphone output. There are a couple of problems with these:

1. Most don't allow you to charge the iPod while the adapter is plugged in.
2. None have a built in line level amplifier. Some might have a headphone amp, but that just puts me back at square one. I'm not looking for more power, just a higher amplitude.

I have found a couple that allow charging such as the FiiO L11 and the PocketDock Line Out USB. Unfortunately they don't appear to have any amplification.

I hope there's something out there I've missed.

Answer (score 3):

actually you do not need amplification. Simply use an adapter like the FiiO L11 (or another cheap 30-Pin > Line-Out + USB-Power-In) an you´ll be amazed: The sound will be way louder and way, way better than the one from the headphone-out. Trust me, I made an A/B-comparison with A=adapter and B=Headphone-Out, both connected to the Line-Ins of an DJ-Mixer and hardly could believe, how much better the sound was!
Cheers from Germany!

Answer (score 1):

Most headphone amps have very little amplification. Check out Sound Shocker. It has plenty of amplification and is totally passive. No batteries or plugin power. It won't charge your iPod but you could use a separate charger.

Comment: Not much info available on the Sound Shocker. Being totally passive, it sounds like a highly marked-up audio transformer.